# How can I get my validation fields to go red and green?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I literally started coding two days ago. I'm working on a project for a job application in which I have to create a form that goes green and red depending on success/error, and I used a YouTube tutorial to guide me through. Everything was going fine until I tried to code the error and success classes (i.e. the fields turning red or green) for the inputs, and after clicking submit nothing happens!

Here is the code I have written so far. Where have I gone wrong?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form class="form" id="form"; action="mailto:changed@email.com"
        method="POST"
        enctype="text/plain:
        name="EmailForm>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" id="name">
    </div>
      <div class="form-control">
      <label>Email</label>
      <input type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" id="email">
      </div>
        <div class="form-control">
      <label>Card</label>
      <input type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9\s]{13,19}"
             autocomplete="cc-number" maxlength="19"
              placeholder="Enter A Proxy Credit Card Number" id="ccn">
        </div>
    
    <button type="submit"; style="background-color:#e70064;
        border-color:#3c3c3b; color:#3c3c3b">Submit</button>
    
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color:fff;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
   
}

.container {
  background-color:#89c82e;
  border: 5px solid #3c3c3b;
  border-radius:20px;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-bottom:15px;
  width:300px;
  max-width:100%;
  
}

.form{
  padding: 30px 40px;
  font-family:"calibri"
}

.form-control.success input {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color:#e74c3c
}
```

JS:

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const name = document.getElementById('name');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const ccn = document.getElementById('ccn');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  checkInputs();
});

function checkInputs() {
  // get the values from the inputs
  const nameValue = name.value.trim();
  const emailValue = email.value.trim();
  const ccnValue = ccn.value.trim();
  
  if(nameValue === "") {
    // show error
    // add error class
    setErrorFor(name)
  } else {
    // add success class
    setSuccessFor(name)
  }
}

function setErrorFor(input) {
  const formControl = input.parentElement; // .form-control
  
  // add error class
  formControl.classname = 'form-control error'
}
```

thanks so much!

Comment: Your HTML is invalid: your `<form>`'s `enctype="text/plain:` attribute needs a closing `"` and you have a semicolon here: `<button type="submit"; `.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

By doing

```
.form-control.error input {
  border-color:#e74c3c
}
```

You are setting any divs with a class name of `form-control error` that has an input inside to have a border color of red. But by default divs don't have a visible border. If you want the input field to turn red or green based on success/failure, set the inputs to have a `border-color`. You have the inputs already at the top of the js file, you can use those.

Also, in the `setErrorFor` function, it is `.className`, not `.classname`.

Comment: How exactly would I do that? Are you talking about the 'const' lines? thank you

Comment: You had the right idea, but it isn't necessary to get the parentElement of the input. You change the input's border color to highlight the field in red. The const lines are fine. They hold the form inputs and those are the ones that you want to change.